# Import only a chunk from a file with LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

Is there a way to import only a chunk from a file with `LOAD DATA` in MySQL, or must I partition the file manually?

Answer (score 0):

you have to partition the file manually.
because LOAD DATA will Load the complete file in table.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
...
IGNORE x LINES
```

[DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to import only a chunk from a file. You would have to partition the file manually. Because load data will load the complete file.